# Integer Programming: Simplify Constraint in Optimisation

Tags: optimization, constraints, transform, logical-operators, integer-programming

I have four variables x1,x2,x3,x4 which takes binary values i.e. (0,1) and 4 sets as-.

```
 s1 = (x1,x2)    
 s2 = (x1,x3)  
 s3 = (x4,x2)  
 s4 = (x4,x3)
```

I want to select minimise number of variables selected such that either one of the set is selected. I used integer programming to model where the objective function is `x1+x2+x3+x4` and the constraint as.

```
x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x4*x2 + x4*x3 >=1
```

I want to linearise this constraint or simplify it so that it is easy to represent and solve.
Doing transformations many extra variables are added which I don't want.